# Directx D3D9 fails to render a primitive on a RenderTarget surface

Tags: c++, directx, rendering

So for some reason DrawPrimitive() doesn't seem to work with my render target surface.

```
// The current target, we must set it back as target afterwards
IDirect3DSurface9* temp_target;
device->GetRenderTarget( 0, &temp_target );

// Craete the surface
IDirect3DSurface9* surf;
surf = NULL;
device->CreateRenderTarget( group->width, group->height, group->format, D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE, 1, false, &surf, NULL );
device->SetRenderTarget( 0, surf );

device->Clear( 0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_ARGB( 255, 0, 255, 0 ), 1.0f, 0 );

sprite->Draw( device, 0, 0, 0 );

// Save the current surface
IDirect3DSurface9* tex_surf = NULL;
texpage->GetSurfaceLevel( 0, &tex_surf );

device->StretchRect( surf, NULL, tex_surf, NULL, D3DTEXF_NONE );

group->texpages->push_back( texpage );

// Set the render target back to what it was previously

device->SetRenderTarget( 0, temp_target );
```

And the sprite draw:

```
void StreamSprite::Draw( LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 device, float x, float y, int subimg) {
    D3DCOLOR colour = D3DCOLOR_ARGB( 255, 255, 255, 255 );
    VERT* vertices;
    RECT rect;
    rect.left = ( long ) x;
    rect.right = ( long ) x + width;
    rect.top = ( long ) y;
    rect.bottom = ( long ) y + height;

    float u1 = ( subimg / img_count );
    float u2 = ( ( subimg + 1 ) / img_count );

    device->SetFVF( D3DFVF_TLVERTEX );

    device->SetStreamSource( 0, buf, 0, sizeof( VERT ) );

    //Lock the vertex buffer
    buf->Lock( 0, 0, ( void** ) &vertices, NULL );

    //Setup vertices
    //A -0.5f modifier is applied to vertex coordinates to match texture
    //and screen coords. Some drivers may compensate for this
    //automatically, but on others texture alignment errors are introduced
    //More information on this can be found in the Direct3D 9 documentation

    vertices[ 0 ].color = colour;
    vertices[ 0 ].x = ( float ) rect.left - 0.5f;
    vertices[ 0 ].y = ( float ) rect.top - 0.5f;
    vertices[ 0 ].z = 0.0f;
    vertices[ 0 ].u = u1;
    vertices[ 0 ].v = 0.0f;

    vertices[ 1 ].color = colour;
    vertices[ 1 ].x = ( float ) rect.right - 0.5f;
    vertices[ 1 ].y = ( float ) rect.top - 0.5f;
    vertices[ 1 ].z = 0.0f;
    vertices[ 1 ].u = u2;
    vertices[ 1 ].v = 0.0f;

    vertices[ 2 ].color = colour;
    vertices[ 2 ].x = ( float ) rect.right - 0.5f;
    vertices[ 2 ].y = ( float ) rect.bottom - 0.5f;
    vertices[ 2 ].z = 0.0f;
    vertices[ 2 ].u = u2;
    vertices[ 2 ].v = 1.0f;

    vertices[ 3 ].color = colour;
    vertices[ 3 ].x = ( float ) rect.left - 0.5f;
    vertices[ 3 ].y = ( float ) rect.bottom - 0.5f;
    vertices[ 3 ].z = 0.0f;
    vertices[ 3 ].u = u1;
    vertices[ 3 ].v = 1.0f;

    //Unlock the vertex buffer
    buf->Unlock();

    //Set texture
    FAILED( device->SetTexture( 0, texture ) );

    //Draw image
    device->DrawPrimitive( D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN, 0, 2 );
}
```

I cut out a few pieces that shouldn't be necessary.

I've also made sure that all functions work properly (don't return an error), I've debugged them all. no errors. It's probably me having some option not set properly somewhere.

Comment: The first step to debugging Direct3D is to ensure that every single function that returns an ``HRESULT`` is checked using the ``FAILED`` or ``SUCCEEDED`` macros or something like [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed). Secondly, you enable the Direct3D debug device and check for any messages. Have you done that?

Comment: Also, why are you using a 12+ year old API instead of Direct3D 11? Note that Direct3D 9 Developer Runtime (i.e. debug device) is not supported on Windows 8.x or Windows 10. Also the D3DX9 utility library is deprecated as is the entire [legacy DirectX SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) itself. In short, unless you have a compelling reason to suffer all the pain required to use Direct3D 9, why not use something better supported (perhaps using [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki))?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I have done that. I've used FAILED() on all functions.I'm using directx9 because this is for a dll that is inserted into an engine that uses directx9